# ASPX not redirecting in Production Azure Stack

Tags: asp.net, redirect, azure-stack

I am deploying a website created in ASP.NET on Azure Stack. There is one ASPX page that I am trying to redirect after authentication, it is working perfectly on my local machine but after publishing it even credentials are correct it is not going to this page. This below code is from CS page.

```
Response.Redirect("~/TestPage.aspx", false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

this page contains

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><b>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTestDashboard" runat="server" /></b>

                </div>
                <br />

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div>
                      DASHBOARD
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

above this a master page is calling into code.

After deployment I am getting issue to redirect to this page but if create a new webpage and trying to redirect then it easily navigate to this new page. I am struggling why this above page is not able to redirect. Is there any issue with this code?

Answer (score -1):

I have checked my master page where is written

**HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name**

It is not supported by AzureStack so instead of this i have passed user name through session then validate that.

string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["UserID"]

and it worked. On Azure Stack Identity will never work.

Comment: What makes you say that HttpContext.User.Identity.Name wouldn't work in Azure Stack? What are you basing that on?